# onclick="animated.open()" not working inside Polymer elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a problem regarding onclick="animated.open()". I try to implement the paper-dialog element, and I want the dialog to open after a click on a paper-fab.

```
<paper-fab icon="create" onclick="animated.open()"></paper-fab>

<paper-dialog id="animated" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
  <h2>Dialog Title</h2>
  <p>Some text here</p>
</paper-dialog>
```

According to the [paper-dialog docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog) this should work, however, it doesn't. By clicking the paper-fab an error pops up in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: animated is not defined

My assumption would be that it doesn't work because all of that is inside a custom element. Does anybody know a workaround? I already tried to use addEventListener but this didn't seem to work either.

Thanks a lot in advance, 
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not correctly accessing the `paper-dialog` element. You will need to create a function that is called from the `on-click` event on the `paper-fab` element which gets a reference to the `paper-dialog` element. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) for more information.

For instance:

```
<paper-fab icon="create" on-click="openDialog"></paper-fab>
```

then define your function `openeDialog`:

```
openDialog: function () {
  this.$.animated.open();
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UCcSLyIqlXn6aMD1M9gY?p=preview) demoing this.